# How can I include two pictures in the \leftlogo or \rightlogo of sciposter?

Tags: logos, sciposter

I am preparing a poster using sciposter and I want to include two logos instead of one in the left/right side of the poster, one logo on top of the other: the top logo aligning with the top of the title and the bottom logo aligning with the bottom of the universities information.

```
\documentclass[30pt,plainsections]{sciposter}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{sectionbox}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{adjmulticol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\makeatletter
\def\@selfnt{}
\makeatother
\let\eachwordone=\normalfont
\let\eachwordtwo=\normalfont
\let\eachwordthree=\normalfont

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{5mm} 
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing


\title{\color{white} \textsc{TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE}}

\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} 
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\author{%
\color{white}
Author 1 \hspace{4em} Author 2 \hspace{3em} Autho 3 \\
\hspace{-2,5em}\affaddr{University1}
\hspace{6em}\affaddr{University2}\\
}

\leftlogo{firstlogo.png}
\rightlogo{secondlogo.png}  %I want to put two logos on one side 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `\leftlogo` and `\rightlogo` commands by

```
\renewcommand\printleftlogo
  {\begin{center}
     \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}%
       {\includegraphics{firstlogo.png}\includegraphics{secondlogo.png}}
   \end{center}
  }
```